# $A/J(A)$ is semisimple as an $A$-module, then $A$ is semisimple

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

$A/J(A)$ is semisimple as an $A/J(A)$- or $A$-module, then $A$ is semisimple.

Is this even true?(by the counterexample kindly provided below this is not.) I am asking this because I've a corollay of Weddernburn's Theorem that goes:

$A$ is a $k$-algebra such that $A/J(A)$ is Artinian. Then the numbers of isomorphism classes of simple left $A$-module and of simple right $A$-modules coincide.

In the proof, the author says $J(A/J(A)) = 0$, hence $A/J(A)$ is semisimple. The result follows from Wedderburn's theorem.

I know that Wedderburn's theorem is about $A$ being a semisimple $k$-algebra. So I asked this. If it is not true, then how to use Wedderburn's theorem. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample: $A=k[x]/x^2$. Note that $J(A)= xA$ and $A/J(A) \simeq k$ which of course is simple as a $k$- and $A$-module.

One should not need Wedderburn's Theorem to conclude that an Artinian ring $R$ with $J(R)=0$ is semisimple, which in what you outline seems to get applied to $R=A/J(A)$.

Then the assertion about the number of isomorphism classes of simple modules follows from the fact that for any ring $R$ there is a correspondence between simple $R$-modules and simple $R/J(R)$-modules (basically because $J(R)$ necessarily acts trivially on simple modules), which induces a bijection of isomorphism classes.

Comment: thx for the input!  My question is then: how to apply Wedderburn's to prove the corollary when we only have $A/J(A)$ semisimple. W's can only be applied when A is semisimple, right? thx!

Comment: Ah, that's where you wanted to apply Wedderburn. See edit.